# Method not getting triggered on click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a popup when a card is clicked. My problem is that I can't get the showPopup function running on click of the card component.

```
//... all required imports 

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      monsters: [],
      searchField: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Fetches monsters and updates the state (working fine)
  }

  showPopup = () => {
    console.log(2);
  };

  render() {
    const { monsters, searchField } = this.state;
    const filteredMonsters = monsters.filter(monster => monster.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <CardList className="name" monsters={filteredMonsters} showPopup={e => this.showPopup(e)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Following is the code for my CardList component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Card } from '../card/card.comp';
import './card-list.styles.css';

export const CardList = props => {
    return (
      <div className="card-list">
        {props.monsters.map(monster => (
          <Card key={monster.id} monster={monster} onClick={props.showPopup} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
};
```

The onclick function above is not working as expected. Please help me find out the problem.

**EDIT** The code for card component

```
import React from 'react';

import './card.styles.css';

export const Card = props => {
  return (
    <div className="card-container">
      <img src={`https://robohash.org/${props.monster.id}?set=5&size=150x150`} alt="Monster" />
      <h2 key={props.monster.id}>{props.monster.name}</h2>
      <p>{props.monster.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you post the Card component?

Comment: `onClick` must be passed down to a clickable element (`button`, `div`, etc). A component itself is not going to fire a click event

Comment: The edit confirms the above is the issue. `onClick` is just a prop. Nothing within `Card` is using that prop, so it's not expected that your function will ever be called. You need to attach that event handler to something that will actually make its way to the DOM, like the `div` inside `Card`.

Comment: I added ```onClick``` to div outside ```Card``` and it works fine. Can you show me a way to render that popup from the ```showPopup``` function?